# What expression should be used to return the total area of all polygons in a layer?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm presuming this must be possible, which may be an error, but I need an expression in Qgis 2.16 which calculates the total area of the polygons in a layer. I intend to use it to give a proportion of cover for each polygon in the layer.

I found [this](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/06/05/qgis-function-editor/) which seems to claim to create such an expression in the editor, but it doesn't work as expected. The preview in the field calculator shows the right answer, but the column in the table is populated with zeros and when I next open QGIS and then open the table it crashes.

I'm not interested in Statist or Groupstats (where similar questions seem to lead) because I need to use the value in my field calculator.

If anyone knows of an expression that would be perfect, but otherwise, can anyone could have a look at the script I've linked and see why it might no longer work (presuming it did once) and suggest any updates?

Comment: Try removing the `x` in `def total_area(x, feature, parent):` so that it reads `def total_area(feature, parent):` then use the expression: `$area / total_area()`. Might not be as elegant as the second version but it seems to work. Tested on QGIS 2.18.0.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doing this just yields an "invalid expression" error when using it in the field calculator. Has Qgis 2.18 gained something that makes this work?

Comment: Did you click the _Load_ button after you made the changes to the script? I will test this on QGIS 2.16.3.

Comment: Yes, just found the tooltip over the total_area expression is saying "EVAL Error: Global name layer_name is not defined", does that help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Ah, I see. I tested the first script in the link you provided, not the second.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there were two scripts on that page, if the first one works I might try it, I avoided it because it said that QGIS froze, but if you've had success, it might do what I need.

Comment: OK, tried that, it has the same outcome, the expression shows up under custom as it should, the 'output preview' in field calculator shows the right result for the first polygon, but when I go to open the table for the layer Qgis freezes

Comment: What field type are you using? Try creating a new **virtual** field with type _real_. Then enter the expression. This doesn't write the values to the shapefile so should be quick to test. The expression works on QGIS 2.14.3 for me so maybe there's an issue with your QGIS version or you have a lot of features in your shapefile...?

Comment: Thanks for persevering, I tried as you suggested, but with the same freeze on trying to open the table. Only 7 polygons in the layer. One is a multi-part feature, could that be mucking it up?

Comment: The multi-part feature could be the problem. Try converting it to singleparts and see if the error still persists :)

Comment: OK, split everything to single parts, still freezing instead of opening the table, 30 polygons in the layer now. I'm baffled. I will upgrade to 2.18 and see if that helps. I can't believe this function hasn't been written in as a standard geometry expression, surely it's quite a frequent requirement among land managers?

Comment: There is a `sum()` function which aggregates the sum of all values in a field. I tend to use something like `($area / sum("fieldName")) * 100` in order to get the percentage proportion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Field Calculator**, there is the aggregate function `sum()` which returns the summed value of a field. So you could create a field (e.g. "Total_Area") which contains the area of each polygon using the expression `$area`.

Then create another field (e.g. "Proportion") to calculate the percentage proportion using the expression:

```
($area / sum("Total_Area")) * 100
```

---

So you don't really need to use those scripts ;)

---

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to [@ndawson's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) comment, you shouldn't need to create a "Total_Area" field at all. You could just use:

```
($area / sum($area)) * 100
```

Comment: This no longer freezes Qgis, but the virtual field is still blank. I've tested it with just $area to check everything else is working and it populates perfectly, but as soon as I use sum("*field_name*") it populates with just blanks.

Comment: @Isaacson - I cannot replicate your issue unfortunately, tested with virtual and non-virtual fields and singlepart, multipart features. Perhaps upload your shapefile to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: I will experiment with some similar layers (the one I'm using is client confidential) and see if I can get it to work. I've marked yours as the answer, as it clearly works somehow, it must be something about my layer preventing it in my case. Thanks for your help

Comment: You should really only mark answers if it **solved your** issue ;) . It could be the layer, QGIS version or something else but hopefully it will work with your other layers. Also, in your `.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory, is there a folder called "processing"? If so, you should delete this and restart QGIS as this could cause conflicts with certain processing tools.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't want any issues specific to my layer to detract from the answer for anyone else looking for the same thing. If I get it sorted on my layer I'll comment so as to complete for this case too.

Comment: Fyi - there's no need to create the Total_Area field in advance. Sum($area) should work.

Comment: @ndawson - Thanks for the tip, for some reason it didn't work on my QGIS 2.16.1 but worked on QGIS 2.18.0.

Comment: I've resolved the problem in my particular case so the answer does apply. For some reason it had to do with the units for the project being set to Hectares. It seemed that Qgis was taking one part of the sum in it's native unit (square metres) and another part in the project units (Hectares), dividing gave a very small number which is rounded to zero. Multiplying the formula by 10,000 gave the results I was looking for.

Comment: @Isaacson - Great! Glad you got the problem resolved =)